# How do you specify column names with psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a SQL statement such as:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2,3)
```

I am using psycopg2 to insert data as follows:

```
 cur.execute(
        sql.SQL("INSERT INTO{} VALUES (%s, %s, %s)").format(sql.Identifier('my_table')),[1, 2, 3]
        )
```

I don't see how to specify column names into the insert statement though? The above sql.sql is "assuming" that 1,2,3 are in order of col1, col2 and col3.  For instance, at times when I want to say insert only col3, how would I specify the column name with sql.sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execute` is just executing the SQL code, so you can just mention the columns as per standard [PostgreSQL INSERT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html) like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_ABC (col_name_1,col_name_2,col_name_3) VALUES (1, 2, 3)"
```